# What aspects of quantum mechanics occur in "Treacle Walker"?

Tags: interpretation, alan-garner

*[Treacle Walker](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/58205835-treacle-walker)* is a (very) short novel by Alan Garner, the author of many classic works of children's fantasy. Published in 2021, it reached the shortlist of the 2022 Booker Prize.

The Booker Prizes [website](https://thebookerprizes.com/the-booker-library/features/reading-guide-treacle-walker-by-alan-garner) describes the book as:

> Joe Coppock, a boy with poor vision, lives alone. His inner world is
> built out of a comic book and the sound of the noon train in the
> valley below his cottage. Then one day a rag-and-bone man called
> Treacle Walker knocks at his door.

but then adds the intriguing detail:

> Quantum physics and the imagination entangle themselves around Joe’s
> subsequent adventures and learning experiences.

A [review in The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2021/nov/01/treacle-walker-by-alan-garner-review-the-book-of-a-lifetime) repeats this point:

> This is a book about quantum physics as well as ancient lore.

Having read the book, I'm at a bit of a loss as to what elements of quantum physics are present in the story. Can someone elucidate what these reviews are referring to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first clue that the book is interested in quantum physics is the epigraph, which reads:

> Time is ignorance

This is a quote from the 2017 book *The Order of Time* by Carlo Rovelli, a theoretical physicist who works in quantum mechanics. Without that quote, I would tend to agree with the OP that the parallels with the quantum world are hard to discern in the novella. However, Garner has offered us this signpost so we can scan the text for clues.

One of the clearest examples is at the end of Chapter XII:

> Treacle Walker was sitting in the chimney, and there was someone else there, opposite, but until he was further into the room Joe could not see who it was. And then he could. It was himself.

This is, of course, impossible. In the novella, it is explained as Joe essentially meeting himself in a dream. In the quantum world, however, the laws of classical physics we're familiar with from the everyday world do not apply. Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle indicates that we can't know both the speed and position of a particle at the same time. While a particle can't be in two places at once, this principle means that to us, as observers, it can - like Joe - appears as though it is.

The uncertainty principle would also appear to be at the root of this quote from Treacle Walker himself:

> 'For at the very moment you have Now, it flees. It is gone.'

He is referencing time here and the way that each moment passes before we can truly appreciate it. But it could equally refer to the way that a particle moves as we measure it, leading to our inability to comprehend both its speed and position simultaneously.

The two Joes may also be a reference to the phenomenon of quantum entanglement. In this, measurements of distinct particles can appear to correlate simultaneously even though they are separated by a distance, giving the appearance they are somehow linked or communicating.

There's a similar echo of quantum uncertainty later in the chapter in this exchange:

> Joe lifted the lid. The chest was empty.
> 'There's nowt there! Where've they gone?'
> 'Where have what gone?' said Treacle Walker.
> 'All them jugs and plates.'
> 'There was one,' said Treacle Walker. 'You took it.'
> 'There was lots! It was full!'
> 'They were shimmerings. You chose the true.'

Quantum mechanics suggests that a thing can be both a wave and a particle at the same time and that when we measure it we "collapse the wave function" - essentially a statistical model - and to our observation, at that point, it becomes either a wave or a particle. This is not so very different from the idea that a chest can contain both many things and one thing until one thing is taken. Opening the chest and being uncertain of what's inside also has overtones of the famous [Schrödinger's Cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat) thought experiment.

The concept that we do not really understand the world around us, and that it does not always behave according to the laws we think we know, permeates the book. Joe sees different things through each eye and encounters beings like Thin Amren and Treacle Walker who give him strange explanations for things and peculiar metaphors that he cannot comprehend.

One of the statements that both Thin Amren and Treacle Walker repeat to Joe is:

> What's out is in. What's in is out.

This is a contradiction in terms, yet such contradictions are exactly what quantum mechanics tells us is at the root of reality. That something can be both a particle and a wave at the same time, yet only appears to be one or the other when we measure it. That two distant particles can somehow be 'aware' of each other. Like Joe, these are things we have to accept about the reality of the world around us, and that that reality is not something we can ever truly comprehend.